# ¿Cómo usar ng-change en un check list?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Quiero saber como tengo que  usar el ng-change para saber cual es el estado de cada checkbox que tengo, anexo el siguente código.

```js
$scope.ShowHide = function () {
            //If DIV is visible it will be hidden and vice versa.
            $scope.IsVisible = self.DocsReqs;
        }
```

```html
<div id="Paso2" class="divPrincipal">
                <div class="col-md-6" ng-controller="ObtenerListaDocumentosController as ctrlCheck2">
                    <b>Documentos Requeridos</b>
                    <label class="checkList" ng-repeat="role in ctrlCheck2.roles">
                        <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.roles" checklist-value="role.Id" ng-model="ctrlCheck2.DocsReqs" ng-change="ShowHide()"> {{role.Descripcion}}
                        <b class="fa fa-paperclip" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miModal"></b>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Y si intentas con ng-click?

Comment: Lo intentaré, te cuento que detalle tengo, con el ng-change al momento de dar click sobre un check box me selecciona todos los check box

Comment: Debes tener el ng-model apuntantando a un mismo valor o variable, puedes hacer varios objetos y que cada ng-model apunte a ese objeto en particular.. Me entiendes?

Comment: Si, comprendo lo que me dices

Comment: Si el error es el que te comente anteriormente logicamente no te va funcionar asi apliques ng-change o ng-click...

Comment: ¿Y cómo puedo hacer para que cada ng-model apunte a cada objeto en particular puesto que el checkbox que lleno es dinamico?

Comment: Perdona la demora, Puedes crear en el objeto un atributo con este valor, por ejemplo tu objeto se llama `objectTest`.. entonces deberias crear un atributo `objectTest:{chechatribute: false}` y esto lo agregarias en un array de objetos, cada ng-model apuntaria a su propio chechatribute